# Unable to store voicemail through odbc in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip, ivr

I am using asterisk 1.8 trying to save voicemail details in database but cli shows this

```
     [Apr  4 18:11:54] NOTICE[6879][C-00000006]: chan_sip.c:25503 handle_request_invite: Call from '' (37.59.2.156:5071) to extension '9900972597869877' rejected because extension not found in context 'default'.
    -- <DAHDI/i1/9634434640-3> Playing 'digits/4.gsm' (language 'yes')
    -- <DAHDI/i1/9634434640-3> Playing 'digits/7.gsm' (language 'yes')
    -- <DAHDI/i1/9634434640-3> Playing 'digits/5.gsm' (language 'yes')
    -- <DAHDI/i1/9634434640-3> Playing 'digits/9.gsm' (language 'yes')
    -- <DAHDI/i1/9634434640-3> Playing 'digits/5.gsm' (language 'yes')
    -- <DAHDI/i1/9634434640-3> Playing 'digits/0.gsm' (language 'yes')
    -- <DAHDI/i1/9634434640-3> Playing 'digits/0.gsm' (language 'yes')
    -- <DAHDI/i1/9634434640-3> Playing 'vm-isunavail.gsm' (language 'yes')
    -- <DAHDI/i1/9634434640-3> Playing 'vm-intro.gsm' (language 'yes')
    -- <DAHDI/i1/9634434640-3> Playing 'beep.gsm' (language 'yes')
    -- Recording the message
    -- x=0, open writing:  /var/spool/asterisk/voicemail/default/4759500/tmp/E2vm3O format: wav49, 0xb7416ecc
    -- x=1, open writing:  /var/spool/asterisk/voicemail/default/4759500/tmp/E2vm3O format: gsm, 0xb741f5b4
    -- x=2, open writing:  /var/spool/asterisk/voicemail/default/4759500/tmp/E2vm3O format: wav, 0xb741fcdc
    -- Span 1: Channel 0/1 got hangup request, cause 16
    -- User hung up
  == Parsing '/var/spool/asterisk/voicemail/default/4759500/INBOX/msg0000.txt': Found
[Apr  4 18:12:14] WARNING[6963][C-00000004]: app_voicemail.c:4086 insert_data_cb: SQL Direct Execute failed!
[Apr  4 18:12:14] WARNING[6963][C-00000004]: res_odbc.c:608 ast_odbc_direct_execute: SQL Execute error! Verifying connection to asterisk [asterisk-connector]...
[Apr  4 18:12:14] WARNING[6963][C-00000004]: app_voicemail.c:4086 insert_data_cb: SQL Direct Execute failed!
[Apr  4 18:12:14] WARNING[6963][C-00000004]: app_voicemail.c:4202 store_file: SQL Execute error!
[INSERT INTO voicemail (dir,msgnum,recording,context,macrocontext,callerid,origtime,duration,mailboxuser,mailboxcontext,flag,msg_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]

  == Spawn extension (voice, 4759500, 4) exited non-zero on 'DAHDI/i1/9634434640-3'
    -- Hungup 'DAHDI/i1/9634434640-3'
[Apr  4 18:12:14] WARNING[6963][C-00000004]: res_odbc.c:608 ast_odbc_direct_execute: SQL Execute error! Verifying connection to asterisk [asterisk-connector]...
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have no odbc connection or no table.

For exact issue check

```
asterisk -rx "odbc show"
```

Comment: i have created an odbc connection and this command outputs `[root@localhost ~]# asterisk -rx "odbc show"

ODBC DSN Settings
-----------------

  Name:   asterisk
  DSN:    asterisk-connector
    Last connection attempt: 1970-01-01 05:30:00
  Pooled: No
  Connected: Yes`

Comment: That mean you have connection. I recommend enable debug( add debug in logger.conf to consoel and do from consolre "core set debug 5") and see sql. After that try do same sql on your db (via odbc isql for example)

Comment: but my above output says that its applying the query but not setting the values `[INSERT INTO voicemail (dir,msgnum,recording,context,macrocontext,callerid,origtime,duration,mailboxuser,mailboxcontext,flag,msg_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]
` Am i missing any settings for voicemail?

Comment: That is nto full query.DEbug will show full. I am sorry, not way predict what you are missing.